# How do I set localStorage items in Angular 4.4.6?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am developing a simple Authentication in Angular 4.4. Mongodb is my database.

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'app/services/auth.service';
....

@Component({
  ....
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username: String;
  password: String;

  constructor(
  ....
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLoginSubmit() {
    console.log(this.username);
    const user = { 
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }
    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if(data.success) {
        this.authService.storeUserMeta(data.token, data.user);
        this.router.navigate(['admin']); //redirect
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']); //redirect
      }
    });

  }

}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  authToken: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  authenticateUser(user) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, {headers: headers});
  }

  storeUserMeta(token, user) {
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user
  }

}
```

I am creating an object when `onLoginSubmit()` is called. The user object will be submitted to the auth service to the backend authenticate route.

I tried to print `data` in **login.component.ts** and this is what I see:

```
{success: true, token: "JWT fklskfldskfldskl45354l5k40fkdlgkfdlgfkdlg0945305;fdls;flsd;flsd;fjfkdjskfjsdkfjdskf49832432", user: {…}}
success: true
token: "JWT fklskfldskfldskl45354l5k40fkdlgkfdlgfkdlg0945305;fdls;flsd;flsd;fjfkdjskfjsdkfjdskf49832432"
user :{id: "123456789", name: "Carlo K", username: "carlok", email: "carlok@gmail.com"}
__proto__
:
Object
```

I have a code above that should set `id_token` and `user` to localStorage using the function `storeUserMeta()`

I don't see the key `id_token` assigned to `JWT fklskfldskfldskl45354l5k40fkdlgkfdlgfkdlg0945305;fdls;flsd;flsd;fjfkdjskfjsdkfjdskf49832432` and `user` key assigned to `{id: "123456789", name: "Carlo K", username: "carlok", email: "carlok@gmail.com"}` in

> Chrome Inspect Element > Application > LocalStorage

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with angular, but as I remember, most of time you need to refer back your current window by `$window.localStorage.setItem()`, may be give a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you expand the Local Storage?

[image]

Look a this StackBlitz example: [LocalStorage example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbxses?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({id: "123456789", name: "Carlo K", username: "carlok", email: "carlok@gmail.com"}));
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: yup. i expanded that area but I did not see the id_token key and user key created

Comment: Is the question solved? Because your mark it as solved.